# Run kvm on top of Amazon EC2: possible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, kvm, amazon-ami

I am a very satisfied user of EC2 for various regular needs.

But, today, I have something more special to do : I would need to run tests / benchmarks of kvm on various machines. Amazon Ec2 various types of AMI would suite my needs: I'll be able to try various levels of performances very easily.

But, EC2 instances are already virtualized over Xen.

So, my question is : can I try to install kvm on top of an EC2 AMI ? Will it run ok ? Any special tweaks needed ?

Thanks in advance

regards

didier

Answer (score 1):

No. Amazon is already a virtualised environment. And even if you did, the benchmarks would be of no use anyway. If you need to benchmark a virtualisation solution, you should do so on hardware which is as close as possible to the hardware you plan to virtualise.